# Can I handle PostBack and refresh differently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

This is a general question I haven't seen an answer for.

Can I tell the difference between `PostBack` and refresh in code to ensure people don't submit the same item repeatedly?

Application is C# based ASP.NET. Code below:

```
protected void SubmitListItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack) //Fires on both submit and F5
    {
        SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
        string alias = user.Email.Substring(0, user.Email.IndexOf('@'));
        if (ListChoice.SelectedItem.Text == "comment")
        {
            SPList TargetList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Offer Comments");
            SPListItem item = TargetList.Items.Add();
            item["Title"] = TitleBox.Text;
            item["Body"] = BodyBox.Text;
            item["OfferID"] = OfferID;
            item["Alias"] = alias;
            item.SystemUpdate();
            TargetList.Update();
            LoadOffers();
        }
        else
        {
            SPList TargetList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Offer Best Practices");
            SPListItem item = TargetList.Items.Add();
            item["Title"] = TitleBox.Text;
            item["Body"] = BodyBox.Text;
            item["OfferID"] = OfferID;
            item.SystemUpdate();
            TargetList.Update();
            LoadOffers();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

Although hitting F5 will send a post request if the previous request was a post. So you'll need to make sure to handle that case as well. The worst case scenario is when a user hits a button repeatedly, sending multiple post requests at the same time. Usually handled by disabling the button when its clicked. It will work differently on different browsers/devices, so you'll need to specify your audience.

Comment: @yuriy I had tried that, but IsPostBack is coming up true on F5. What would you recommend as a code branch to tell the difference?

Comment: @Wesley there is no way to do it. You'll have to tell us more about your case so you don't have duplicate data.

Comment: @Wesley would you still like me to take a look at the code, or did you figure it out?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I added the code above. The only thing I can think of that might help is adding unique ID's to each comment and checking to see if they exist. I don't know if the server can tell the difference between the postback and refresh.

Comment: @Wesley One thing to consider is to put a `Guid` in the page's `ViewState`, and also into the `Session` for every response. Then when the page comes back with a Post, you check if the value coming from the `ViewState` is current. That way if somebody presses submit twice, the value in the `Session` will have changed, any you'll know the person has already submitted. There will be usability issues to consider with this approach.